# What is bucket pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

- What is the difference between a pointer and bucket pointer?
- What is bucket pointer in C/C++?
- What are the advantages and drawbacks of using them?

Comment: "Bucket pointer" has no special meaning. It's probably a pointer to a bucket. Whatever a bucket is. Depends on the context.

Comment: @Jon google finds some hits. For instance here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708448/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-bit-bucket-pointer-c-c

Comment: @izomorphius I think what Google find here is just noise: e.g., http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/FoldingSet_8cpp_source.html is just a pointer to a bucket, and I even find something refer to drawing tools. 5520 results does not seem convincing that this is some special thing, or is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Usually the term bucket refers to a subcontainer in a hash table or hash container.  Elements that have the same hash code are stored in the same bucket.  A bucket could be implemented as a pointer to some storage such as a raw array, the head of a linked list, or a pointer to an implementation class.  A pointer could be a pointer to anything - a variable, an object, a variable, ... etc..

Comment: @Fred Nice article link. Thx.